# Will adding more recruitment beacons make settlers come more often?

Tags: fallout-4

In a settlement, if I have one recruitment beacon, settlers don't come very often. If I add another one, will settlers come more often than if I have one?

.

***NOTE:***

I'm not sure if you actually *can* do more than one. I am asking this question to see if I should make another, or if it will be pointless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[No, the game only checks if there is a beacon in a settlement.](https://www.reddit.com/r/falloutsettlements/comments/405lk9/psa_settler_recruitment_and_raid_chances/)

Only happiness increases the chance.

Build bars ( lvl 3 restaurant) to get +40 happiness.

No new settlers will come if you have five settlers that are not assigned to anything.

Comment: But I only have about 550 caps and 4 or 5 level 1 stores. I can't get level 3, because I don't have cap collector lvl 2.

Comment: Get the perk or buy the lvl 1 store. By the way, stores generate caps and each settlement can generate up to 50 caps each day. So dont build more then oné shop if you are using supply lines.

Comment: Okay, but what if I have companions that are unassigned? Do those count, too?

Comment: If they  are assigned to the settlement then I would guess they do.

Comment: Wow, that link is super useful.